# Figure out position with compass bearing

Tags: trigonometry

Scenario: You have two people in the same room, both transmitting their compass bearing.

Question: Is it possible to figure out which direction the other person is standing just from the compass bearing? If possible, how would that be done mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. I can face in the same direction (with respect to north) and still move around. So it is impossible to figure out where the other person could be just knowing what their orientation is.

Comment: What if you had their change in compass orientation as they moved or rotated?

Comment: Same answer. If I tell you I am facing west right now (I am!), you have no idea about my position. In two minutes I will get up and face north (bathroom break). You still have will no idea about my position. Hence you cannot figure out your bearing to me.

Comment: Ok so what additional information would I need so that this problem is solvable?

Comment: Compass bearing to two known positions maybe?

Comment: I don't think that works either but thanks for the help though.

Comment: What information do you have?

Comment: For what I'm trying to do, GPS isn't accurate enough especially indoors so as far as position goes, all we really have is compass bearing.